# when i hit run on turtle t says there is no attribute turtle on line no.2/3(depends on space of line)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

aye_turtle = turtle.turtle()

aye_turtle.forward(100)

aye_turtle.right(90)
```

I've tried this on repl.it for a lot of time but it never worked out

Comment: Please share the entire error message. The issue seems quite basic to me, have you done any research?

Comment: https://repl.it/@ayedan/turtlepy please check the link

Comment: Is that in response to my comment?

Answer (score 1):

```
import turtle

#the first letter of the Turtle object is uppercase
aye_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

aye_turtle.forward(100)

aye_turtle.right(90)
```